# Index after split string function in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `Địa chỉ` with a long string separates by commas:

```
'Đường Minh Khai, Phường Minh Khai, Quận Hai Bà Trưng, Hà Nội'
...
'Đường Khương Trung, Phường Khương Trung, Quận Thanh Xuân, Hà Nội'
```

I want to get the second string element after splitting it with a lambda function (the 'Phường xyz' part).

I'm trying:

```
func = lambda x:x.split(',')[1]
nhahn['phuong'] = nhahn['Địa chỉ'].apply(func)
```

However, the `[0]` index works but the `[1]` index, which is the one I need, gave an error of

> "list index out of range".

Why is it the case and how do I fix it? Thanks.

[The index [0] works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cng9X.png)

[But index 2 doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdHvw.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `str[1]` for select second value, if not exist return `NaN`:

```
nhahn['phuong'] = nhahn['Địa chỉ'].str.split(',').str[1]
```